# blank screen when trying to open a screen in angular

Tags: angular, flutter

I am using flutter and angular, I want to send an email from flutter, in that email there is an href tag with a button that takes you to a screen, the href has a paramentro but what I click on takes me to the screen but it appears in white.

Its localhost.
When I try to open the screen, only localhost appears in the url

ERROR error also appears Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: NG04002: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'Re%C3%B1a'
Error: NG04002: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment:

code:

flutter

```
final url = 'http://.../RestablecerC?tokenU=$tokenUsuario';

final smtpServer = gmail(dotenv.env['...'].toString(),dotenv.env['...'].toString());
     final message = Message()
       ..from = Address(dotenv.env['SMPTGMAILCORREO'].toString())
     ..recipients.add('${Correo}')

 ..html = '''
      <h1>Recuperación de contraseña</h1>
      <p>Para cambiar la contraseña, utiliza el siguiente token:</p>
    
      <p>También puedes hacer clic en el siguiente botón para restablecer tu contraseña:</p>
      <a href="$url">
        <button style="background-color: #007bff; color: #fff; padding: 10px 20px; border: none; cursor: pointer;">Restablecer Contraseña</button>
      </a>

Angular

{path:'RestablecerC/:tokenU',component: PantallaRComponent},
```

Answer (score 0):

I placed following code and the screen appeared, it is no longer blank.

```
{path:'RestablecerC',component: PantallaRComponent},
```